# Scrape Data From a sports table using Python and Beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the data from a table - namely (http://stats.nba.com/leagueTeamGeneral.html?pageNo=1&rowsPerPage=30). I am having difficulty with using the right commands. Tried various parameters, none worked. Ideally having the data returned in the format, 
example: 
Atlanta Hawks,32, 48.8, 18, 14, .563, etc
I can get the data formatted no problem, just getting the required data is what is causing me grief.

```
    import urllib2
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    page = 'http://stats.nba.com/leagueTeamGeneral.html?pageNo=1&rowsPerPage=30'
    page = urllib2.urlopen(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    for dS in soup.find_all(???):
        print(dS.get(???))
```

Comment: Also, per the html, the required data is in ,<tr class = 0> where the number represents each team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a tool like firefox firebug to track down the html call you need, looking at the link you shared in firebug 'net' tab shows that the data you are after is in a subsequent request call to `http://www.nba.com/cmsinclude/desktopWrapperHeader_jsonp.html`
which actually contains json data, not sure BeautifulSoup will be handy here, try to load it using python `json`

Answer (score 1):

Thank for the suggestion, Worked rather nicely. What I ended up using was something like

```
    import json
    from pprint import pprint

    with open('NBA_DATA.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

    #Have this here for debug purpose just to see output
    pprint(data["resultSets"])

    for hed in data["resultSets"]:
        s1 = hed["headers"]
        s2 = hed["rowSet"]
        #more debugging
        #pprint(hed["headers"])
        #pprint(hed["rowSet"])
        list_of_s1 = list(hed["headers"])
        list_of_s2 = list(hed["rowSet"])
```